# How many arguments takes the foldr function of Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, arguments, fold

I am new to Haskell and I am reading the book  ["Real World Haskell"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#fp.tailrecursion). In the Chapter 4 of the book the author asks as an exercise to rewrite the groupBy function using fold. One of the readers of the book (Octavian Voicu ) gave the following solution:

```
theCoolGroupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
theCoolGroupBy eq xs = tail $ foldr step (\_ -> [[]]) xs $ (\_ -> False)
                       where step x acc = \p -> if p x then rest p else []:rest (eq x)
                                          where rest q = let y:ys = acc q in (x:y):ys
```

**My question is simple:** I know that foldr takes 3 arguments: a function, an initial value and a list. But in the second line of the code foldr takes 4 arguments. **Why this happens?**
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott's answer is correct, the result of the `foldr` is a function, so this is why it seems that `foldr` takes 4 arguments. The `foldr` functions does take 3 arguments (function, base, list):

```
*Main> :type foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

I'll just give here an example that is less complex:

```
inc :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
inc v = \x -> x + v

test = inc 2 40  -- output of test is 42
```

In the above code, `inc` takes one argument, `v`, and returns a function that increments its argument by `v`.

As we can see below, the return type of `inc 2` is a function, so its argument can simply be added at the end:

```
*Main> :type inc
inc :: Int -> Int -> Int
*Main> :type inc 2
inc 2 :: Int -> Int
*Main> :type inc 2 40                                                        
inc 2 40 :: Int
```

Parentheses could be used to emphasize that the return value is a function, but functionally it is identical to the above code:

```
*Main> (inc 2) 40
42
```

PS: I'm the author of the original comment :)

Answer (score 10):

In this situation, I think it is best to look at the type signature of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

and to match that to the expression we have (with added parenthesis for clarity):

```
(foldr step (\_ -> [[]]) xs) (\_ -> False)
```

The second argument of `foldr` is the same type as its result. In this case the second argument is a function. In this case, this means that the `foldr` expression with 3 arguments will be a function.

What you see to be the 4th argument of the foldr function could also be thought of as the 1st argument of the foldr result!

Answer (score 8):

All functions in Haskell take just one argument. When we have a function with type `a -> b -> c`, it is just a shorter way to write `a -> (b -> c)`, i.e. a function, which takes one argument and produces a function which takes another argument. See [Currying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying) for more information.

In this case, see the @sepp2k's answer. `foldr` produces a function and it needs another ("the 4th") argument.

Answer (score 3):

In this case `foldr` is used to build up a function. `(\_ -> False)` is the argument to that function.