# Why can foldr take a function with three arguments?

Tags: function, haskell, types, arguments, fold

I was having a look at some list operations and came across [`!!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#%21%21):

```
(!!)                    :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n
  | n < 0     = negIndex
  | otherwise = foldr (\x r k -> case k of
                                   0 -> x
                                   _ -> r (k-1)) tooLarge xs n
```

The function `(\x r k -> ...)` has type `a -> (Int -> a) -> Int -> a`, but `foldr` takes a function that should only accept two arguments:

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

Can someone explain to me why `foldr` accepts a function that takes 3 arguments with the following type `a -> (Int -> a) -> Int -> a`? Especially since the result should have the same type as the second argument?

Comment: Questions like this are asked about foldr often, but I can't find anything good enough to mark this as a duplicate of. Anyone have an idea? The best I could find are https://stackoverflow.com/q/15879940/625403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4733019/625403.

Comment: `->` in types is right associative. Your function type can also be written `a -> (Int -> a) -> (Int -> a)`.

Comment: Yeah, I see that with such step function `r` is out `go` that already has `ys` and waits for `(k-1)`, question can be closed, thanks to all

Comment: With more parens added - foldr takes a function `fn :: a -> (Int -> a) -> (Int -> a)` and returns a value of type `(Int -> a)`. After foldr is done this n gets applied to this function: `(foldr fn tooLarge xs) n`.

Comment: @amalloy neither is an exact duplicate. This question can be rewritten as "why can foldr take a function with three arguments?".

Comment: The type of `tooLarge` should be a big hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is right-associative. So `a -> b -> c` is `a -> (b -> c)`. Therefore, your type

```
a -> (Int -> a) ->  Int -> a
```

is the same as

```
a -> (Int -> a) -> (Int -> a)
```

and  we can see that it fits `foldr`'s type quite well.

Answer (score 2):

(more explanation for others ;)

```hs
(!!)                    :: [a] -> Int -> a
xs !! n
  | n < 0     = negIndex
  | otherwise = foldr (\x r k -> case k of
                                   0 -> x
                                   _ -> r (k-1)) tooLarge xs n

foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
--                                   ^1          ^2
```

`foldr` commonly makes an accumulated(?) value. In this case, `foldr` makes an
accumulated function (`b`) of the type `(Int -> a)`! `foldr ... tooLarge xs` is evaluated to an
accumulated function, and this accumulated function (`^2`) takes an argument `n`. `^1` is a `tooLarge` function. Interestingly, the buildup of this
accumulated function depends on the value of a free variable `n` (i.e., `k`).

For example, `['a', 'b', 'c'] !! 2` is evaluated like below:
`\x r k` = `\'a' r 2 -> r (2-1)` (`r` is not known yet, and drives further evaluations.)
`\x r k` = `\'b' r 1 -> r (1-1)`
`\x r k` = `\'c' r 0 -> 'c'`

`['a', 'b', 'c'] !! 3` goes like this:
`\x r k` = `\'a' r 3 -> r (3-1)`
`\x r k` = `\'b' r 2 -> r (2-1)`
`\x r k` = `\'c' r 1 -> r (1-1)` (`r` turns out to be `tooLarge`.) = `tooLarge (1-1)` (ERROR!)

You can check debug traces:

```hs
module Main where

import Debug.Trace

tooLarge _ = errorWithoutStackTrace "!!!: index too large"
negIndex = errorWithoutStackTrace "!!!: negative index"

(!!!)                    :: Show a => [a] -> Int -> a
xs !!! n
  | n < 0     = negIndex
  | otherwise = foldr (\x r k -> trace ("x: " ++ show x ++ ", k: " ++ show k) $
                                 case k of
                                   0 -> x
                                   _ -> r (k-1)) tooLarge xs n

main = do
  print $ ['a', 'b', 'c'] !!! 2
  print $ ['a', 'b', 'c'] !!! 3

-- x: 'a', k: 2
-- x: 'b', k: 1
-- x: 'c', k: 0
-- 'c'
-- x: 'a', k: 3
-- x: 'b', k: 2
-- x: 'c', k: 1
-- sample: !!!: index too large
```

---

This `(!!)` implementation is a report version. The report version of the prelude is more efficient than a familiar naive recursive implementation,
due to optimizations of `foldr`.